# C# arquivos que preciso enviar para o cliente (colocar em um instalador por exemplo)

Tags: c#, winforms, instalador, .exe

Boa noite,

---

> Quais arquivos são obrigatório na distribuição do meu EXE?

---

[image: Arquivos]

A pasta **pusblish** é porque eu cliquei em publicar uma vez para testar e agora ela sempre é gerada a cada Debug ou Release (Se alguém souber como desabilita ela pode tá comentando por favor)

**App.application**  -> também faz parte do publish

**O .exe**           -> lógico tem que ir

**App.exe.config**   -> não sei exatamente para que serve, mais ao meu ver não deveria ir

**App.exe.manifest** -> acho que tem a ver com o assembly do EXE

**App.pdb**          -> armazena as informações do Debug

**info.xml**         -> ESTE eu criei mesmo, tem que ir

O restante **(dlls e xml)** seriam dependência do projeto (EXE) e tem que ir junto

Acima coloquei alguns eu acho, porque apesar de achar que não precisa ir junto, eu estou colocando porque quando tento executar o EXE sem eles, acaba que dá error
As vezes não é quando abre o EXE, mas quando está usando, já deixando os arquivos que acho que não precisa, funciona normalmente.

Se todos forem necessário alguém responde ai por favor, e **gostaria de saber o motivo exatamente se possível**. Obrigado desde já

Netframework 4.5, usando VS 2019

Comment: Fazer um instalador é totalmente diferente de fazer um publish para criar um "zip" para distribuir a aplicação. Qual o seu objetivo??

Comment: Eu quero  fazer um instalador da minha aplicação. Eu por exemplo estou usando o inno setup para colocar todos estes arquivos no instalador.

Comment: Com respeito a questão da diferença não entendi muito bem. Pelo que vi no VS 2019 o Publish tem o objetivo de gerar um instalador também ... Apesar de ser simples mais gera, inclusive até com a opção de update (algo que também vou precisar), na pasta do Publish gera um instalador e não simplesmente um "zip" para distribuir. Talvez não tenha entendido bem, mais ao meu ver o Publish também é para a questão de instalador, só que acabei achando limitado (ou eu não soube usá-lo bem) por isto voltei para o inno

Comment: Se não tiver um projeto de instalador na sua solução, nenhum instalador será gerado. Como vc diz que há, então edite a sua resposta e informe que o vc tem e o que já tentou fazer. Sem adicionar essas informações fica impossível saber o q vc tem e o q pretende.

Comment: @tvdias Na verdade eu não tem o projeto de instalador. Esta opção de publish tem no VS 2019 (versão community) ... só clicar com o botão direto e clicar em publish

Comment: Tem certeza que esse publish gerará um instalador!? Além do mais, especifique na sua pergunta a versão do framework que e usada.

Comment: Sim, gera um instalador. Alterei a pergunta com a informação, só não consegui pensar em que ajudaria :)